# How to work with a dom element

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to know if a textarea is in focus. I am doing something like this:

```
if (document.activeElement === 'textarea') {
   console.log('You are in a textarea');
}
```

Comment: @MagicMan No, he knows how to get the focused DOM element (as in the example). This question is about how to test what type of tag the element represents.

Comment: I could do something like: if (document.activeElement === document.body) {}, but I liked adeneo's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the tagName

```
if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'textarea') {
   console.log('You are in a textarea');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check textarea have focus or not ,two of them are as below
  1.  if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA' || document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    //Something's selected
}

2.
if ($(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "text" ||     $(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "textarea") {
  //Something's selected
}